# ¿Cómo importar con PHP contenido de texto de un <div> desde otro archivo HTML?

Tags: php

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Supongamos que tengo un archivo llamado `ejemplo1.html`. Dentro del archivo tengo esto:

```
<div id="textoejemplo"> Aquí tengo el texto que quiero importar.</div>
```

Ahora supongamos también que tengo otro archivo llamado `ejemplo2.php`.

¿Cómo podría asignarle a una variable `$texto` dentro de `ejemplo2.php` como valor el HTML -o texto- interno que contenga `<div id="textoejemplo">`, teniendo en cuenta que a su vez está dentro de `ejemplo1.html`?

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: No he entendido muy bien ... ¿Quieres hacerlo como input con un `$_POST` como formulario, o lo quieres tener en un `archivo.php` aparte con variables asignadas anteriormente y solamente pasar el mismo texto a las dos páginas?

Comment: @Lukas, quiero básicamente importar el contenido de texto de un '<div>' dentro de un primer archivo HTML, a una variable en un segundo archivo que contiene todo mi código PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una función que primero abra y lea el contenido de un fichero, en este caso de "ejemplo1.html", y guarde este contenido en una variable, ahora ya tienes todo el contenido que necesitas (y algo más) como un string, solo necesitas extraer la parte que necesitas y volcarla como resultado de la función en la variable $texto, es decir algo como esto:

```
    getHtmlContent( $path ) {

       //logic here

       return $str;
    }
    $path  = "ejemplo1.html";
    $texto = getHtmlContent( $path );
```

o algo más complicado pero que te permita extraer otros contenidos, con un segundo parámetro para indicar los elementos delimitadores del texto a extraer:

```
getHtmlContent( $path, $delimiters ) {

    //logic here

    return $str;
}

$path  = "ejemplo1.html";
$delimiters = "div#textoejemplo";
$texto = getHtmlContent( $path, $delimiters );
```

Esta segunda función tendría que extraer un contenido dinámicamente segun lo pasado, aceptando por ejemplo tags HTML sin más, o con una cierta clase, ID, elementos anidados, etc.

Yo te lo pongo como una sencilla manipulación de string, pero si vas a hacer algo complejo, existen librerías para generar y manipular un DOM a partir de documentos HTML.

Comment: Esto me sirve, muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Usar DOM

Para obtener el contenido de una página en una variable, la forma más sencilla es utilizando [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php).

Una vez que se tiene la variable con el texto de una página HTML, la forma de procesarlo es utilizando [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Toda la información que necesitás para procesar un X/HTML, ya sea en este caso o cualquier otro, está en http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php.

### Pasos

Estos son los pasos necesarios para obtener el contenido de un elemento por su ID:

1. Generar el objeto del documento con [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) antes de empezar.
2. Cargar el texto del HTML en el documento con [loadHTML()](http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtml.php).
3. Obtener el div por su id llamando a [getElementById()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php).
4. Extraer el texto del elemento desde la propiedad [textContent](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent).

#### Código [<kbd>demo en phpfiddle.org</kbd>](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/t09t-zpda)

```php
<?php

    $url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/Kp8Wu5QM'; //subí tu ejemplo a pastebin
    
    //Obtener el texto de la página web
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    
    //Generar el DOM
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET);
    
    //Obtener el elemento por el id "textoejemplo"
    $textoejemplo = $doc->getElementById('textoejemplo');
    
    //Obtener el texto del elemento
    $texto = $textoejemplo->textContent;
    
    //Imprimir el resultado
    echo "Texto: " . $texto;
```

Comment: Esta es una buena solución, dada la extensión del documento a procesar.  El problema de usar DOM es el consumo de recursos para procesar documentos grandes.

Comment: @Orici Si bien uno siempre debe estar atento al uso de recursos, ya estamos en el 2017. Cualquier servidor puede soportar una tarea sencilla como esta. DOM es la forma correcta de manipular HTML.